# VB.NET issue loading textboxes with data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I have some textboxes (using VS2010) I'm trying to populate with values from columns in a SQL Server database based on what item someone selects from a combobox. At first I was able to display the values for the first item in the combobox, but now nothing at all displays when I debug. Code:

```
Private Sub loadfields(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles client_selection_combobox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using myconnection As New SqlConnection("connection string")
        Dim loadfields As String = "SELECT company FROM ClientFileDatabase WHERE ClientFileDatabase.File_Name=@company;"
        Dim loadfields_sqlcommand As New SqlCommand(loadfields, myconnection)
        loadfields_sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        loadfields_sqlcommand.Parameters("@company").Value = client_selection_combobox.SelectedIndex.ToString

        Dim loadfields_dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        loadfields_dataadapter.SelectCommand = loadfields_sqlcommand

        Dim loadfields_dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
        loadfields_dataadapter.Fill(loadfields_dataset, "ClientFileDatabase")
        Dim loadfields_dataview = New DataView(loadfields_dataset.Tables("ClientFileDatabase"))

        companyname_textbox.DataBindings.Clear()
        companyname_textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", loadfields_dataview, "Company")
        taxid_textbox.DataBindings.Clear()
        taxid_textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", loadfields_dataview, "TaxIDNumber")
        accountmanager_textbox.DataBindings.Clear()
        accountmanager_textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", loadfields_dataview, "AccountManager")
        etc...
    End Using
End Sub
```

I've also tried using the SelectedValueChanged and SelectionChangeCommitted event handlers to no avail. Also tried using a refresh after setting the databindings, didn't help. Any advice welcome, thanks!

Comment: asp.net or windows forms?

Comment: You don't retrieve the field's data  for TaxIDNumber and AccountManager. Is this just a typing error or do you really just "select company from ...."

Comment: That was a typing error, sorry. It's windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use datatables, I find them easier to work with. I'm sure you will have more code to check to make sure dt.rows.count > 0 before actually attempting to work with the data, but here is how I would do it.

```
Dim loadfields_dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
loadfields_dataadapter.Fill(dt)

companyname_textbox.text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Company")
taxid_textbox.text = dt.Rows(0).Item("TaxIDNumber")
accountmanager_textbox.text = dt.Rows(0).Item("AccountManager")
```

Also, keep in mind that NULL fields in the database can cause runtime errors, so you may have to check for those as well.